# Finding pdf original

Tags: pdf

I have a PDF file located on a hard drive. On that same hard drive is the original using a different name. There are thousands of files on the hard drive. Can I find out what and where the original is that created the pdf?

Comment: Do you know what application the source document is written in, and which application was used to create the PDF?

Comment: Windows? Linux? Mac?

Comment: If the files are exact duplicates, any duplicate file finder will do. Otherwise you need to answer the queries posted above.

Answer (score 1):

Open the PDF with Acrobat, and pick File->Preferences. Information about the original file may be in a few places.

Many programs that output PDF will put the filename in the Title field.  Information about the creator of the file can be found in the PDF Producer field.

[image: Screenshot of Adobe Acrobat Document Property Window with highlights calling out the Title and PDF Producer Fields.]